# Typically long running query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I inherited a poorly designed SQL Server implementation, with horrible database schemas, and several pitifully slow queries/views that take hours, or even days, to execute.

I'm curious: What might an experienced DBA/SQL programmer consider to be an unusually long time for a query to take? In my professional experience I'm not used to seeing queries *(for views or reports, etc)* that take more than maybe an hour or two to run. We have several here that take 1-2 days or more!

*(This database has no relationships, no Primary Keys, no Foreign Keys, hardly any indexes, duplicate data all over the place, old data that shouldn't even be in the tables, temp tables everywhere, and so on...ugh!)*

What do you consider within the realm of acceptable or normal for a lengthy query process?

I'm trying to do a sanity check to determine how awful this database really is...

Comment: How awful the database really is?  I'd hit it with [sp_blitz - by Brent Ozar & co](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) to get a damage report.

Comment: Subjective -- if this were a data warehouse (OLAP), hours could be the norm... But with the clarification you gave on no relationship, pk, fk, indexes, etc all signs point to significant room for improvement.

Comment: We just installed a brand-new SQL Server box and I'm slowly and carefully migrating the old data to a set of new, cleaner, better-designed databases. But until we get this done, we have to suffer with the existing mess. I'm just hoping we can rebuild and rewrite so that these super long queries run like 2x to 10x faster!

Comment: You can't really say what is an "acceptable" time to complete in generic terms. What is long time for one query might be considered normal for another. It all depends on what work the query is doing and how time critical the operation is. For example, slow inserts into a data warehouse are likely to be less of an issue than slow inserts into an OLTP database. That said if something is taking days to complete you've usually got problems!

Comment: It depends on database size. Queries that query tables with hundreds of millions of rows and return millions of rows have different expectations than queries that query tables with thousands of rows and return hundreds of rows. In general though, I don't like any query that takes longer than 90 seconds unless it's an extremely complicated and comprehensive "report" meant to run over-night or something.  Even then, hours is my limit. You should look at adding indexes to speed things up.

Comment: I appreciate the comments from you folks, and it does tell me that is probably is quite unreasonable for these queries to take so long. Our tables have anywhere from 1-100 million records, but there are no inserts or appends or anything, no OLTP or OLAP stuff, just plain tables; we're really just selecting data from generally 1, 2 or more tables, with a few WHERE parameters and a couple of simple CONVERT functions etc. Should really not take long to run most of these, IMO, if they're written right and the databases are configured correctly. 

I believe it is as I suspected...THANX!

Comment: If your business uses don't want to wait that long and they have the budget to fix it then it's unacceptable. That's my metric. But practically speaking queries that run for days is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question, it's just easier to offer this script to you here than in a comment.

You might want to run this query and see what SQL Server thinks are the missing indexes it needs to perform better (a short-term solution while you migrate to your new schema and database).  DO NOT BLINDLY APPLY THESE INDEXES. These are merely suggestions for you to consider, that SQL Server itself has identified as being useful when it runs.  You might select one or two, perhaps tweaking include columns, and AFTER TESTING, apply some of them to help you speed up your existing system (I forget where this query came from, so I'm sadly unable to attribute the original author):

```
SELECT 
  migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) AS improvement_measure, 
  (migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans)) AS [cumulative_impact],
  OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) as TableName,
  'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' + CONVERT (varchar, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' + CONVERT (varchar, mid.index_handle) 
  + '_' + LEFT (PARSENAME(mid.statement, 1), 32) + ']'
  + ' ON ' + mid.statement 
  + ' (' + ISNULL (mid.equality_columns,'') 
    + CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN ',' ELSE '' END 
    + ISNULL (mid.inequality_columns, '')
  + ')' 
  + ISNULL (' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement, 
  migs.*, mid.database_id, mid.[object_id]
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
WHERE migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) > 10
  AND database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY migs.avg_total_user_cost * migs.avg_user_impact * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) DESC
```

Further, you can use the following script to find the "longest running queries" (along with their SQL Plans).  There's a TON of information here, so play with the ORDER BY to bring different kinds of issues to your attention at the top (for instance, the longest running queries might run only once or twice, while one that runs thousand of times might not take SO long, but might consume far more resources all told):

```
SELECT [St].Text,
       [Qp].[Query_Plan],
       [Qs].*
  FROM (SELECT TOP 50 *
          FROM [Sys].[Dm_Exec_Query_Stats]
         ORDER BY [Total_Worker_Time] DESC
) AS [Qs]
       CROSS APPLY [Sys].[Dm_Exec_Sql_Text] ([Qs].[Sql_Handle]) AS [St] 
       CROSS APPLY [Sys].[Dm_Exec_Query_Plan] ([Qs].[Plan_Handle]) AS [Qp]
 WHERE ([Qs].[Max_Worker_Time] > 300 OR [Qs].[Max_Elapsed_Time] > 300)
   AND [Qs].execution_count > 1
 ORDER BY min_elapsed_time DESC, max_elapsed_time DESC
```

These queries only return data from running instances.  Stopping and restarting SQL Server erases all the collected data, so these queries are only really valuable for systems that have been up and running in "real world" situations for a while.

I hope you find these useful.

Comment: Thanks very much, pmbAustin, I'll give those a try!